# Select using other calculated properties

Tags: powershell, select

Is there a way to use a calculated property in the same select statement for another calculated property.  Or do you have to have another separate select for this?

I'm using PowerCLI from VMware to try to produce some memory stats (total, provisioned, % provisioned) for hosts.

```
get-vmhost | sort Parent |
  select Parent, Name, @{Name="MemoryTotalGB";E={[math]::Round($_.MemoryTotalGB)}}, @{Name="MemoryProvisionedGB";Expression={$_ | get-vm | measure -sum MemoryGB | select -ExpandProperty Sum}} |
  select Parent, Name, MemoryTotalGB, MemoryProvisionedGB, @{Name="MemoryProvisionedPercentage";E={[math]::Round($_.MemoryProvisionedGB / $_.MemoryTotalGB * 100)}} | ft
```

In the first `select` statement, I calculate the sum of VM memory running on the host as `MemoryProvisionedGB`.  In the 2nd I do the % provisioned using this sum.

Is it possible to somehow reference the calculated property `MemoryProvisionedGB` in the first select statement to produce the % calculation?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you have the collection calculated just once (Although, BenH's `ForEach-Object` suggestion is more elegant)?

```
Get-VMHost |
  Sort-Object -Property 'Parent' |
  Select-Object -Property @(
    'Parent'
    'Name'
    @{ N = 'MemoryTotalGB'
       E = {[Math]::Round($PSItem.MemoryTotalGB)}
     }
    @{ N = 'MemoryProvisionedGB'
       E = {($PSItem | Get-VM | Measure-Object -Sum 'MemoryGB').Sum}
     }
    @{ N = 'MemoryProvisionedPercentage'
       E = {[Math]::Round(($PSItem | Get-VM | Measure-Object -Sum 'MemoryGB').Sum /
                          [Math]::Round($PSItem.MemoryTotalGB) * 100)
           }
     }
  ) | Format-Table
```

Comment: I avoided this specifically because the Get-VM operation can be expensive.  With a large inventory and a remote connection, the less blanket Get-* statements the better.

Comment: @raidzero If you're worried about cost, you should utilize `ForEach-Object` then or be forced to use double `Select-Object` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using calculated properties, you could use a `ForEach-Object` loop and create a `[pscustomobject]`. This would allow you to create several variables to reuse.

```
Get-VMHost | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $MemoryTotalGB = [math]::Round($_.MemoryTotalGB)
        $MemoryProvisionedGB = ($_ | Get-VM | Measure-Object -Sum MemoryGB).Sum
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Parent' = $_.Parent
            'MemoryTotalGB' = $MemoryTotalGB
            'MemoryProvisionedGB' = $MemoryProvisionedGB
            'MemoryProvisionedPercentage' = [math]::Round($MemoryProvisionedGB / $MemoryTotalGB * 100)
        }
    } |
    Sort-Object Parent |
    Format-Table
```